# Lua Variable, Table, For Loop Syntax

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table

Just saw this in the Lua self examples...

```
  -- Example 24   -- Printing tables.
  -- Simple way to print tables.

  a={1,2,3,4,"five","elephant", "mouse"}

  for i,v in pairs(a) do print(i,v) end


  -------- Output ------

  1       1
  2       2
  3       3
  4       4
  5       five
  6       elephant
  7       mouse

  Press 'Enter' key for next example
```

I haven't seen this syntax before, `for i,v in pairs(a) do print(i,v) end`

Where did the `v` come into existence ?

Does the word `in`  cause it to exist ?

By the same token, where does the `i` come into existence ?

Is this a syntax designed for tables ?

Thanks for any explanation.

Comment: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.5 and http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-pairs also http://lua-users.org/wiki/ForTutorial and http://lua-users.org/wiki/IteratorsTutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pairs` returns an iterator over all fields and their values

more exactly it's a function of table and previous seen index which returns pair of index and its value.

```
> t = {4,5,6}
> p = pairs(t)
> =p(t)
1   4
> =p(t,1)
2   5
> =p(t,2)
3   6
```

there are 2 options: iterate over every keys or just those which are integers:
`pairs` and `ipairs` functions

this loop is very similar to python's

```
l = [4,5,6]
for i, v in enumerate(l):
    ...
```

or

```
d = {"a":1, "b":2}
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    ...
```

if you know python (it looks like everyone knows it)

Comment: To prevent confusion: `ipairs` doesn't iterate over all keys that are integers; It iterates from 1 to n-1, where n is the index of the first nil value encountered.